# How do you use anonymous functions in React Router's route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

What's the purpose of passing `props` to the anonymous function below? Do you have to use an anonymous function in order to pass props down to a component inside a route?

```
function App(props) {
  const { data } = props;

  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/home" render={(props) => <Home data={data.things} />} />
    </Router>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the source of this code that leads you to ask this question? Or is this something you made yourself?

Answer (score 0):

So to answer your question:
In the above code we have to pass the `props` in the anonymous function so that they are available to the `Home` component.
Ideal way is to pass the props like below:

`<Route path="/abc" render={props => <TestWidget someProp="2" {...props} />} />`

Beautifully explained [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105)

In case you are using redux then all this will be taken care by the store using the higher order component `Provider`. Please refer to the docs [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/UsageWithReactRouter.html#connecting-react-router-with-redux-app)